# I can't scan an integer starting by 0. This number is completely different. Why is it different? And how can I fix it?

Tags: c, integer

Hereunder is my function. I do not get why my variable date, if it begins by 0 is wrong.

```
void demandeInfoReservation(client_t* h){
    ...
    while(!(correct)){
        printf("Encodez votre date d'arrivée (jjmmaaaa)");
        scanf(" %i",&date);
        h->date.annee=date%10000;
        date/=10000;
        h->date.mois=date%100;
        date/=100;
        h->date.jour=date;
        correct=correcte(h);
        if(!(correct)){
            printf("la date que vous avez encodée n'existe pas.");
        }
    }
```

I tried scanf(" %01d", &date) but i do not get to anything good.

Comment: Always check what [`scanf` ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). If the user inputs something that is not a number (like letters) you will never know. In fact, I recommend you forget that you forget that `scanf` even exits, and instead use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read full lines and then use e.g. `sscanf` or `strtol` to convert (with validation and checking) to  number.

Comment: This is defined behavior for `%i`.  If you don't want that behavior, you shouldn't be using `%i`.  For some reason `%i` is very popular these days, as if lots of instructors are teaching to use it all the time, by default.  But this is poor instruction, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas `scanf()` is the reason for too many SO questions, too often OP code tries to cleverly *fiddle* with bits'n'pieces of data.

The following is probably not as elegant as it could be, but seems to accept/reject user input as is desired in this question:

```
int main() {
    int y, m, d;
    for(;;) {
        printf( "Enter dd.mm.yyyy - " );
        if( scanf( "%d%*c%d%*c%d%*[^\n]", &d, &m, &y ) == 3 )
            printf( "%4d/%02d/%02d\n", y, m, d );
        else
            scanf( "%*[^\n]" ); // discard bad entry and try again.
    }
    return 0;
}
```